# How to query first month of data for each user

Tags: mysql

**Problem Description**

I have a data table `multiplayergame`where there are multiple records for each `UserID` detailing their activities during that multiplayer game, and the date `DateID` that the game occurred on.

**Question**

How can I query the games for each user that occur within **the first month of their first game** ? i.e., Grab all the rows for that user that occur within 30 days of the first record for their first multiplayer game?

Comment: You can use `between` 30 days from the start date and sys.date

Comment: But each user has a different start date ; i.e., one user may have had their first occurence November 2013, another January 2014, etc.  . Wouldn't your solution only grab the first month of data, period? Not capturing the data for users who started after the first month?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @potatosoup can you give me the query you tried so far?

Comment: You can simply check the date for 30 days after their creation date

Comment: `select userid, min(dateid) as da from multiplayergame
    where d < dateadd(d,30,da)
    group by userid`

Comment: @potatosoup See my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be slow if you have a lot of users, but it will work. The subquery gets a list of UserID's and their first game's DateID, then selects all the games where the DateID is between this date and the next 30 days (for each user). If you added the first game date to the user table or used the user created_at date you could speed it up a lot because of the full use of indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM multiplayergame m1 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(m.DateID) as first_game, m.UserID
FROM multiplayergame m
GROUP BY m.UserID) der on der.UserID=m1.UserID and m1.DateID BETWEEN der.first_game AND der.first_game + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works like a charm. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Something like the following will give you the rows:

```
WHERE   create_date BETWEEN create_date() AND DATE_ADD(create_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes just like @Pritam Banerjee 's answer CURDATE(). But select tables *.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    multiplayergame
WHERE   DateID BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

You could also use NOW()

```
SELECT  *
FROM    multiplayergame
WHERE   DateID BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```